# Build Error on TFS "The server was not found or was not accessible." using Redgate for CI and CD integrating databases

Tags: database, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, redgate

I am learning about how to integrate the databases in the continuous integration and deployment. I followed the examples on this two tutorials: [Tuorial from Redgate Website](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Continuous+integration), and this: [Write Cool Code Blog](http://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2017/05/17/deploying-database-changes-in-your-continuous-delivery-pipeline-with-redgate-readyroll-and-visual-studio-team-services/), I created a simple project for test and I am working with a very simple script for the migrations that just add a new column to the table. When I run the Build I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ReadyRoll\ReadyRoll.Data.Schema.SSDT.targets(146,5): Error : An error occurred while attempting to verify your deployment scripts: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Can someone help me with this problem? How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A network-related or instance-specific error could be of many reasons. Please check the things below to narrow down the issue:

- Ensure SQL database and services are running.
- Make sure  the **Firewall** is not blocking the communication
- Ensure the build service  account does have the required permissions
  to the SQL Server database.
- Ensure Network connectivity is OK between the Build Server and SQL
  Server
- Check for network protocols that are enabled on the SQL Server
  (**TCP/IP**) must be enabled. Once enabled, please restart the services for it to take effect

More ways have a look at this question  which maybe helpful:[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)